# Problems with getting data from a page using python, beautiful soup

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to explore the web scraping in python.Currently working with beautiful soup.I was trying to get names of the festivals from this site : https://www.skiddle.com/festivals .Everything was going pretty fine, except 1 page, this one: https://www.skiddle.com/festivals/front-end-data-test/. It says 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find' any way i can get data from there?
Here is the code

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import lxml
import json


headers = {
    "user-agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.5060.114 Safari/537.36 OPR/89.0.4447.64"
}

#collect all fests URLs
fests_urls_list = []


#for i in range(0, 120, 24):
for i in range(0, 24, 24):
    url = f"https://www.skiddle.com/festivals/search/?ajaxing=1&sort=0&fest_name=&from_date=15%20Aug%202022&to_date=&maxprice=500&o={i}&bannertitle=August"

    req = requests.get(url=url, headers=headers)
    json_data = json.loads(req.text)
    html_response = json_data["html"]

    with open(f"data/index_{i}.html", "w", encoding="utf-8") as file:
        file.write(html_response)
    with open(f"data/index_{i}.html", "r", encoding="utf-8") as file:
        src = file.read()

    soup = BeautifulSoup(src, "lxml")
    cards = soup.find_all("a", class_="card-details-link")

    for item in cards:
        fest_url = "https://www.skiddle.com" + item.get("href")
        fests_urls_list.append(fest_url)
#collect fest info
for url in fests_urls_list:

    req = requests.get(url=url, headers=headers)

    try:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, "lxml")


        fest_name = soup.find("div", class_="MuiContainer-root MuiContainer-maxWidthFalse css-1krljt2").find("h1").text.strip()

        fest_data = soup.find("div", class_="MuiGrid-root MuiGrid-item MuiGrid-grid-xs-11 css-twt0ol").text.strip()
        print(fest_data)
    except Exception as ex :
        print(ex)
        print("This was not supposed to happen")
```

Comment: Can you confirm what information exactly are you looking to scrape, for each festival?

Comment: im looking for the title of the festival and date, but the main trouble is not about the info, i wanna get but about the fact that i can't get any information from that  particular page, i guess that it's because of the java script thing at the start of that page,request module  just can't get any information from it, but that's only my guess.from all other festivals it's collect info perfect